# throw an error message before a segmentation fault due to wrong vector initializzation

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, std

I'm pretty new of c++.
I am in the following case: I need to resize an std vector which I don't know if it was correctly initialized.

If the vector was not initialized this cause a segmentation fault.

Is there any way to check if the vector where correctly initialized?
Is there any way to print a message before the program crash for the segmentation fault?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I don't know if it was correctly initialized"?  In what circumstances would it not be initialized?

Comment: `std::vector` do not need any particular initialization, after the constructor has run (and you can't avoid it unless you do very scary things) it is in a consistent state, that should not generate segmentation faults on resize. What the hell are you doing to make it blow up like that? :)

Answer (score 1):

vectors have constructors that ensure they are always correctly initialised. The problem is probably with the class or whatever that you are storing in the vector. Post some code that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

vector uses the default constructor of the contained object. For an operation like resize, this default constructor will be used. If it segfaults on resize, its probably due to a problem in your constructor.